# Vertically Align texts with different sizes in <a>

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, font-size

I want to align an addition(plus) mark and text next to it, however, since the "+" is too small, it is enlarged with a  tag. This causes the character to become too big, making it hard for me to align them. How would I align the + character and Text evenly next to each other?

This is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rs75V/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

or

```
vertical-align:-10%;
```

? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/rs75V/33/) looks all right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

I think it's what you're looking for, it has a ton of different ways to move text alignment up or down.

Answer (score 0):

It's hackish, but this should work.

```
a{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;    
    background-color: #EEEEEE;


    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;

    color: #333;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EEE;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer; 
}
span{
    font-size:40px;
    vertical-align:-15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating your `a` and `span`.

```
a{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;    
    background-color: #EEEEEE;

    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;

    color: #333;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EEE;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
span {
    font-size:40px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 .1em 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the span as an inline-block and then use padding on it...

```
a{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;    
    background-color: #EEEEEE;


    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;

    color: #333;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #EEE;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer; 

}
span{
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```